# Define Enumeration object and value class on same level

Tags: scala

Is it possible to declare an Enumeration object and class on the same level in Scala?

I started with this, but I am not sure what is the best way to register the instances.

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
  val MALE = new Gender(0)
  val FEMALE = new Gender(1)
}

class Gender(val id: Int) extends Gender.Value {

}
```

The motivation for this is that I don't want to refer to the enum class as Gender.Gender, but Gender.

Comment: Isn't an object an instance of a class, so you can't apply a `new` on it?

Comment: Yes, but new Gender refers to the class and not the object, this code compiles and the enum constants will be accessible, but the Enumeration will not know about them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
    val male   = new Gender
    val female = new Gender

    class Sneaky extends Val(nextId, null)
}

class Gender extends Gender.Sneaky

> println(Gender.values)
Gender.ValueSet(male, female)
```

However I do not really feel good about it. I think it would be better either
to make a type alias (if you can at this scope):

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
    ...
}

type Gender = Gender.Value
```

Or `import` the type before you use it:

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
    val male, female = Value

    type Gender = Value
}

import Gender._
val x: Value = male
```

(Or, if you can, use case classes).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Using type aliases or imports are not an option in this case.